# Cannot find module @angular/core

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

So I'm trying to learn a bit on how to use Angular and set up the basic configuration that Visual Studio has for making a site.  I was in the process of trying to figure out why I kept getting a message that there was no provider for HTTP and then I started getting an error at startup about how it couldn't find the @angular/core module.  I rolled back the changes I made trying to resolve the HTTP provider message and am still getting the error about @angular/core.  I am keenly aware that the version of Angular used is way out of date, but since I'm just trying to get a feel for it and this isn't for public use, I'm not all that concerned.

If anyone has ideas, it would be appreciated.  If anyone knows how to address that HTTP Provider thing, that would also be appreciated.

Here is the full exception that I receive:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: 'Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "../../../node_modules/@angular/core"
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:19316:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:19199:87)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:19141:92)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
    at Object.hasOwn (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:17218:77)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:19432:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
Current directory is: C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test
'
```

Since I'm not sure what file is the source of my problem, I'm listing what I think would be the most likely candidates here:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Angular2Test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app.server.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        ServerModule,
        AppModuleShared
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

app.shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/Shared/Header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/Shared/Footer/footer.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/Login/login.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

Here is a list of some of things I've looked at to try and resolve this:

- [Error: Cannot find module '@angular/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780833/error-cannot-find-module-angular-core)
- [error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359043/error-ts2307-cannot-find-module-angular-core)
- [Can not find module '@angular/core' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080628/can-not-find-module-angular-core-error)
- [angular2: Cannot find module '@angular/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484442/angular2-cannot-find-module-angular-core)
- [Cannot find module @angular/core + angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213055/cannot-find-module-angular-core-angular2)
- [cannot find module '@angular/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530798/cannot-find-module-angular-core)
- [Cannot find module '@angular/core' in new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715848/cannot-find-module-angular-core-in-new-project)
- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: npm install in your ClientApp folder.

Comment: @penleychan - Just tried that and no change.  No error on the npm install command, but trying to start the site back up produced the same message about @angular/core not being found.

Comment: npm install --dev inside your project

Comment: What is the node and npm version ?

Comment: @RANJIT PATRA
C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test -> error is generated about there not being a package.json file in this directory
C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test -> Warning that the use of -dev is deprecated and to use --only=dev instead.  States that it was up to date in 2.664s.
C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test -> Warning that the use of -dev is deprecated and to use --only=dev instead.  States that it was up to date in 2.681s.
@angular/core message still appears.

The node version is 8.11.3 and the npm version is 5.6.0

Comment: Run the `npm install --only=dev` inside the folder where `package.json` is available.  I think it is inside 'C:\Users\MyName\source\Angular2Test\Angular2Test'.

Comment: @RANJIT PATRA - ran that, same @angular/core error when attempting to start.

Comment: Can you try with realigning modules in `dependencies` and `devDependencies`. as you have added everything in `devDependencies`. Also please share error log when you are doing `npm install --only=dev`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184932/discussion-between-ranjit-patra-and-brad).

Comment: @RANJIT PATRA - PM> npm install --only=dev
up to date in 2.704s
PM>

Comment: @RANJIT PATRA - I'm not sure what you mean by realigning modules in dependencies and devDependencies, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Just in case someone comes across this - Ranjit Patra and I spent a bit of time going over possible causes and were not able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Run

> npm install

inside your Angular project

Comment: I'm afraid I no longer have this solution on my computer to test if this would resolve the issue.